# Marshal.Copy fails

Tags: c#

My problem is that the `Marshal.Copy` fails because of the size.
My size for some reason is 4, although the actual size of my array is over 200kb.
Can you explain my error with size?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    public class ImageData
    {
        public IntPtr Data { get; set; }
        public int Width { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }
        public int ColorOrder { get; set; }

        public void ReadHeaderLessImage(string path, int width, int height,int colorOrder)
        {
            byte[] fileData = null;
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                throw new FileNotFoundException(path);
            }
            fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            this.Height = height;
            this.Width = width;
            this.ColorOrder = colorOrder;
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(fileData[0]*fileData.Length);
            this.Data = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

            try
            {
                Marshal.Copy(fileData, 0, this.Data, size);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged [c++-cli]?  That looks like C#.

Comment: I thought that marshal copy is a part of c++/cli.  This way you copy managed byte[]  into a uint8*...  But maybe I'm wrong

Comment: `Marshal.Copy` is a part of the .NET runtime library.  Your code has no more connection to C++/CLI than it does to VB.NET or F#.

Comment: I'm using this code later on to connect the IntPtr into a c++/cli project.  But i will relabel the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misplaced a parenthesis in this line:

```
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(fileData[0]*fileData.Length);
```

should have been

```
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(fileData[0])*fileData.Length;
```

Of course, since the data type is `byte`, you can just use

```
int size = fileData.Length;
```